# Can i see non-static members of a class with IDA?

Tags: ida, c++

I was making C++ addon headers for BlockLauncher Addon with IDA, reverse engineering libminecraftpe.so file.
While doing that, i got trouble.
I want to see specific class's non-static members but i cant find non-static member view.
Is there a way to see non-static members?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Non static members are allocated as a structure.  For virtual functions there is also a pointer to a table of pointers that is the first offset in the structure.  Each class member is a specific offset from the beginning of the structure.  The easiest way to see this is to create a class, and assign different members to values that you know.  Then look in IDA and see the offsets that are modified with those known values.

Here is a good article that describes the layout. http://www.openrce.org/articles/full_view/23